# Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to install illuminate/html in my Laravel 5.3 app:

```
$ composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package illuminate/html is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laravelcollective/html instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared() in /var/www/qa-laravel/vendor/illuminate/html/HtmlServiceProvider.php on line 36


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                   
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()  


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I did change the vendor path if that caused something to go wrong in composer.json:

```
{
    ...
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "vendor-dir": "../vendor"
    }
}
```

Classes are being loaded OK, I just can't install this new package. Any obvious reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

That package is not compatible with Laravel 5.3. The `->bindShared()` function was removed as of 5.1 and is now `->singleton()`.

Further, the Form Helper package was removed for a reason; it doesn't save any time and introduces complications that aren't necessary. No purpose in using it; remove it.